# error: 'Application-defined or object-defined error' when using CopyFromRecordset - Excel macos

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, adodb, recordset

I am calling data from a PostgreSQL database into an Excel spreadsheet using the following macro:

```
Sub sub_copy_Recordset()

    Dim objRecordset As Recordset
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim input_portfolio, setRange As String
    Dim end_date As Date
    Dim i, record_count As Integer

    input_portfolio = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_portfolio").Range("main").Cells(1, 1).Value
    end_date = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_portfolio").Range("main").Cells(2, 1).Value
    ini_date = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_portfolio").Range("main").Cells(3, 1).Value

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        strConnection = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=[ip];Port=5432;Database=[db];UID=user;PWD=[pwd];"
        Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        objConnection.Open strConnection

        With objRecordset
            .ActiveConnection = objConnection
            .Open "SELECT * FROM portfolio_positions('" & input_portfolio & "','" & end_date & "');"
        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_tables")
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            record_count = objRecordset.RecordCount
            objRecordset.Close
            Set objRecordset = Nothing
        End With

objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing

    MsgBox "End Sub"

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

    Debug.Print Err.Number & "  " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

When the macro executes the line where I copy the recordset to cell "A2" `.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset` it copies the data to A2 and jumps to the end of the Sub and executes line `MsgBox "End Sub"`. When I add additional instructions below the CopyFromRecordset line as next:

```
Sub sub_copy_Recordset()

    Dim objRecordset As Recordset
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim input_portfolio, setRange As String
    Dim end_date As Date
    Dim i, record_count As Integer

    input_portfolio = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_portfolio").Range("main").Cells(1, 1).Value
    end_date = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_portfolio").Range("main").Cells(2, 1).Value


    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        strConnection = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=79.143.185.46;Port=5432;Database=fincerec_canaima;UID=fincerec_user;PWD=_Or0cua1@;"
        Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        objConnection.Open strConnection

        With objRecordset
            .ActiveConnection = objConnection
            .Open "SELECT * FROM portfolio_positions('" & input_portfolio & "','" & end_date & "');"
        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("_tables")
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
            record_count = objRecordset.RecordCount
            objRecordset.Close
            Set objRecordset = Nothing

            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 20
            .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 5
            With .Columns("C:G")
                .ColumnWidth = 12
                .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            End With
            setRange = "A" & record_count + 2 & ":G1000"
            .Range(setRange).ClearContents
            setRange = "A2:G" & record_count + 1
            .Names("_positionsRange").Delete
            .Range(setRange).Name = "_positionsRange"
        End With

objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing

    MsgBox "End Sub"

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

    Debug.Print Err.Number & "  " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

It copies the recordset in cell A2, but then jumps to ErrHandler: and then reports error

> 1004  Application-defined or object-defined error

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comment out the error handler and you can see which line  has the problem.  I'm thinking it doesn't like `.Columns("C:G")`

Comment: Thank you. I changed the line you referred to. I commented out the error handler but the macro still jumps to the end to line 'MsgBox "End Sub"' after executing CopyFromRecordset, it doesn't stop in any line, doesn't report any error.

Comment: Without an error handler it should not be "skipping" lines.  Are you saying if you step through with F8 then it goes straight from the CopyFromRecordset line to the MsgBox line?  If Yes there's something missing here.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. If I step through with F8, it jumps from CopyFromRecordset to the end of the Sub.

Comment: I can't explain that.  Without an error handler every line should run.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - there are times I can step through the whole macro line by line.